# Jquery check boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to do the following:

I have three checkboxes:

Hide Box1


Hide Box2


Hide Box3

I want to use Jquery to:

When Box1 checked, hide box 2 and 3, if unchecked make box 2 and 3 visible.  Also where do I place the code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkMeOut" id="box1"/>Hide Box1

</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkMeOut" id="box2"/>Hide Box2

</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="">Hide Box3
</form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
if($("#box1").attr("checked")==true)
{
    alert("Checked");
}
else
{
    alert("Unchecked");
}
</script>

Comment: post code in question where it can be formatted, not in comments. Code shown is invalid for checkbox syntax also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example using the markup you gave in the comment. I also took the liberty to give the checkbox's labels which means when you click the text it will toggle the checkbox (more accessible and usable).

[See on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWCzc/2/)

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div class="toggle-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkMeOut" id="box1" />
        <label for="box1">Hide Box1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkMeOut" id="box2" />
        <label for="box2">Hide Box2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="box3" />
        <label for="box3">Hide Box3</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.toggle-checkbox input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.toggle-checkbox').not($(this).closest('.toggle-checkbox')).hide();
    } else {
        $('.toggle-checkbox').show();
    }
});
```

To include jQuery in your page, place the following within your `<head>` tag.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works on JS fiddle but when I put it in my notepadd++ and refresh my chrome nothing works.  DO I need to have something installed?

Comment: Did you include jQuery? Provided you have the .toggle-check divs everything should work.

Comment: Thank you this work perfectly!  I need them to float inline and not in list style though

Comment: No problems, remember to accept the answer by clicking on the tick. To float inline you could change the .toggle-checkbox elements to spans. http://jsfiddle.net/JWCzc/5/

Comment: I ran into some problems,  the whole code stop working and I made no changes,  All i did was shut down my pc open the file in firefox,chrome,IE to test it again, IE and Chrome worked then after reloading them no activity when I click the boxes.

Comment: Open up the page and click a check box in chrome, then press F12 and click on the little red cross at the bottom left corner of the screen to view any javascript errors. If there aren't any maybe try make a jsfiddle so i can check it out?

Comment: The little red cross return this:Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: That means you haven't included jquery in your page, link it up and it should all be good.

Comment: ok can you guide me to where to put it and what it should look like?

Comment: Thank you so much you have been nothing but great help one love and respect man

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in between  tags

```
$('.one').click(function () {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').not(this).hide();
} else {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').not(this).show();
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/MYASr/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your checkboxes have the ids "box1", "box2" and "box3":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box1").change(function(){
        $("#box2, #box3").toggle();
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but anytime hide box 1 is checked or unchecked, it will toggle the visibility of the other two boxes.

The optimal place for your code would be inside of a script element located just before your closing body tag, so something like

```
<body>
Your page stuff here
<script>
Code from above here
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: David Chase's answer will definitely help you more if you wanted to use other boxes. It also makes better use of jQuery's selectors. The location for the script would be the same though.